# bz2 in javascript

Tags: javascript, bzip2

Are there any javascript libraries that can take a byte array and bz2 decompress it into another byte array?  I know that many browsers have this capability for an entire stream, but this array is at an offset from the start of the stream.

Comment: Are you doing this in a browser? Or using node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Here's ont for byte array: https://github.com/antimatter15/bzip2.js
And for binary strings: https://github.com/kirilloid/bzip2-js

Comment: Great solution.  I will just remark that while the input for the first js is a byte array, the output is a string, which threw me off at first (i'm not exactly a js guru)

Comment: Here's also a Java applet http://kirilloid.ru/sc2replay/bzip2.jar with `BzipWrapper.class`, which have `decode` and `decodeBytes` methods with `(* data, int compressedLength, int length)` signature. `decode` accepts data as base64 encoded string, and `decodeBytes` accepts it as uint8array.